# Docker : using pv (pipe viwer) output nothing on build process

Tags: docker, pipe, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm trying to use the `pv` command in my Dockerfile but nothing is displayed on screen when I call the building process.

I made a very simple version of my Dockerfile :

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pv

RUN echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." | pv -L 5 -s56 > /dev/null
```

If I run the command in a simple terminal i've got this output :

```
35 B 0:00:07 [5.35 B/s] [================================================================>                                         ] 62% ETA 0:00:04`
```

But when I run my docker build like this `docker build -t foo .` I only got this :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> 040bf8e08425
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pv
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 155e9ebf615f
Step 3 : RUN echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." | pv -L 5 -s56 > /dev/null
 ---> Running in 3afdb7b5822c
 ---> 6fcf83d0cd02
Removing intermediate container 3afdb7b5822c
Successfully built 6fcf83d0cd02
```

Is there a way to have this `pv` command to work ?

Thank you !

Comment: Your pv happens during `docker build` and as you have  no CMD nor ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile, nothing happens, this is normal

Comment: but the echo is well done if I put out the `> /dev/null` part. So why not the output of `pv` ? And the CMD and ENTRYPOINT are for the run process not for the build right ? Actually I'm lauching the `build` command not the `run` one

Comment: Commands that runs during docker build have no access to terminal so pv cannot work.

Comment: Thanks for answers, but i really don't undersand. What is an "access to terminal" ? the pv command works because the echo is slowed by the `-L 5` option. And the output of echo command works too. The only output that don't work is the one of `pv`. What is the diffrence between the way `pv` output something and the way `echo` does ?

Comment: @user1918998 Did you ever find out why the `pv` output isn't visible whereas the `echo` output is?

Answer (score 5):

Use `pv -f` or `pv --force` and it will work the way you expect it to. Quoting the man page for pv:

```
   -f, --force
          Force output.  Normally, pv will not output any visual display if standard error is no  a  terminal.
          This option forces it to do so.
```

I don't know if this was an option three+ years ago when this question was posed, but it works now.

With this in my Dockerfile like so:

```
RUN echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." | pv -f -L 5 -s57 > /dev/null
```

I get the following as an example output along the way:

```
Step 3/3 : RUN echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." | pv -f -L 5 -s57 > /dev/null
  ---> Running in 57c657f93610
25.0 B 0:00:05 [5.21 B/s] [==============>                     ] 44% ETA 0:00:06
```

... also, to get the "100%" right, you either need to run `pv -s57` or `echo -n`  to suppress the newline.